# want to do searchbox using jquery in ci

Tags: jquery

In this code value is fetching in `var a` but it is not going to controller search function so the value is not posting in model.

---

`$.ajax` url is not going to `search()`

---

```
View page:This is my view page.search.php

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function()
  {
  $("#n").keyup(function()
   {
     var a=$("this").val();
     $.ajax({type:"POST",url:"<?php echo base_url().'index.php/control/search'?>",data:{n:a},success:function(data)
  {
  $("#d").html(data);
 }
 });
}); 
});
</script>





<input type="text" id="n">

<div id="d"></div>


 controller:

 class control extends CI_Controller {


public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('search');
}
public function search()
{       
 $this->load->model('model');
 $q['data']=$this->model->searchd();
 if($q)
 {
 $this->load->view('searc1',$q);
 }
}
}

  Model Page: 
   class model extends CI_Model {
public function searchd()
{
    $n=$this->input->post('n');echo $n;
    $q=$this->db->query("select * from det where name like '$n%'");
    $row=$q->row();
    return $row;
}

 }
```

view: in this page name will be shown fetching from table. This is searc1.php. Now it's working but how to fetch multiple name?

---

```
echo $data->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$row=$q->row();` : `row()` method is using to get first result row from db result, you should load all results try `result()` method to get all fetched results

`$row = $q->result();`

Comment: its working but what is the syntax for displaying through result()

Comment: you should use JSON in server response in apply loop thing to display result set data, see this [link](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/jquery/live-search-using-jquery-ajax-php-codeigniter-and-mysql) good example step by step